Config file does not list newly created branch
I know there are 2 ways to create a branch. Remotely using a gui version control like GitHub or locally using git bash. When I create a new branch remotely and fetch the changes using git bash, the new branch is listed in my config file in the .git directory.
However, when I create a branch locally using git checkout -b <branchname> it is not listed in the config, but when I check its creation using git branch -l it is listed as it should be. Why is this? It is only after I specify the remote counterpart for the local branch that it is listed in the config.
I have created a new branch using git checkout -b <branchname>. I expect at least the [branch "branchname"] entry to appear in the config file, but nothing appears.

Branches don't need to be "listed in config". What's listed in config, like a link to a remote branch, are optional branch attributes. You might just want a local branch, not linked to anything remote.

Instead of looking in the config, you want to notice the existence of $GIT_DIR/refs/heads/$branch_name  That file is created when you create a branch.  The entry in the config just associates the branch with a remote, and not all branches have an upstream (hence, no entry in the config).

There is a known feature of git checkout [name], when [name] does not exist yet locally but exists on a remote:

-- from git help checkout:
If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name and --no-guess is not specified, treat as equivalent to
$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>


The added section in .git/config comes from the --track <remote>/<branch> part, not from the fact that you create a local branch.

Thank you for your clarification, good answer
